# Empty spans move other spans up

Tags: html, css

```
  <span style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;">
    <span style="display:block;">Harvard</span>
    <span>John Smith</span>
  </span>

  <span style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;">
    <span style="display:block;">Chicago</span>
    <span>Tucker Max</span>
  </span>

  <span style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;">
    <span style="display:block;"></span>
    <span>Rihanna</span>
  </span>

  <span style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;">
    <span style="display:block;">NYU</span>
    <span>Peter Simpson</span>
  </span>
 //... and many more
```

The first span contains the university, the second span contains the name of the person. Now my problem is that whenever a I have a person who did not go to uni, I want to simply leave it blank.

But when I do that the name of the person moves up and is not aligned with the other names anymore. So in my example, Rihanna moves up:

[image: Example]

I could write something like `-` or `no uni`, but I would much prefer to have a blank field there, as its just more tidy. I  would also much prefer to have a CSS based solution.

Edit: If people downvote this, let me know why at least.

Comment: Until you learn the necessary CSS basics to know what possible ways of dealing with this could be, I suggest you simply put a non-breking space into those “empty” spans.

Comment: thanks. why not help me out with the css though?

Answer (score -1):

```
<span style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;">
  <span style="visibility:hidden;">&nbsp</span><!-- Change is in this line -->
  <span>Rihanna</span>
</span>
```

You can use "visibility:hidden" style. That way the height/width from the span will still be used while hiding the element.